# Hartl Rails5 tutorial 6.3 Can't create user through terminal or seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through [Hartl's rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users) and I'm stuck on the end of chapter 6 where I'm supposed to create a user in the rails console.  It won't save to my database.

This is what I type into the console:

> User.create(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")

console output:

> (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "mhartl@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>      (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
>   => #

I don't know why it says `User Exists` because the User table is empty.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

Comment: Try a different email address and see if it gives you the same kind of error.

Comment: Try with `User.create!` to get an exception to see why it fails.

Comment: @SteveCarey same result

Comment: @Iceman ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email is invalid

Comment: Double check the email regex then.

Comment: @Iceman Yep, that was it.  Missing a back slash.  I checked it for mistakes after I wrote it, but I still missed it. Thanks.